# How would I, in jQuery remove the extra parts of this string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

So I'm trying to change this string :

```
9 days from now Write about "go to market strategy" - 0.03 - 8100
```

To this :

```
Write about "go to market strategy"
```

How could I do it in javascript or jQuery *without the use of regular expressions* ?

Any answers here appreciated.

Comment: That's not really what jquery does

Comment: Just to clarify, you have something like `var str = '9 days from now Write about "go to market strategy" - 0.03 - 8100';` and you want `str = 'Write about "go to market strategy"` ?

Comment: @Tapha please start making your questions more complete. When you post incomplete questions you keep creating a deluge of bad answers based on guesses. Define the criteria more precisely for this string. As it stands right now your question can be interpreted different ways

Comment: `var input = '9 days from now Write about "go to market strategy" - 0.03 - 8100'; var output = input.split("now")[1].split(" - ")[0].trim();`

Comment: Also show what you tried. This just looks like no effort was attempted to solve this problem yourself and you expect others to do your work for you

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you want to get the title which is between double quotes and insert it in another phrase.

```js
function answer(yourString) {
    // Get the first double quote position
    var start = yourString.indexOf('"')+1;
    // Get the second double quote position
    var end = yourString.indexOf('"',start);
    // Get the subject
    var subject=yourString.substr(start,end-start);

    //result
    return 'Write about "'+subject+'"';
}
```

Comment: They need the text after `from now` and before the ` - `. :)

Comment: @JamesPederson this is an ambiguous point of the question, maybe **Tapha** would be kind to provide more examples of what is needed. Nevertheless you bring a valid concern, but the answer provide a solution that fit the question.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
var str = '9 days from now Write about "go to market strategy" - 0.03 - 8100',
    separator1 = "from now",
    separator2 = ' - ';
str = str.substring( str.indexOf( separator1 )+separator1.length+1 );
str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf(" - "));
console.log( str );
```

It uses the `.indexOf()` method to find the strings and `.substring()` to shorten the main string.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree that this solution  also fit the question, additionaly I hope @Tapha would get the gist of the solution, which is using the `indexOf` method

Comment: Absolutely, that's the main idea of it :) Mine just lets him store whatever strings he wants to read the content between, and calculates the lengths of them to accommodate.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you are going to want to parse out other strings within the larger string that something other than 'go to market strategy'. With that being said, you're going to want to think about what the 'red flag' will be (delimeters). However, for what you're asking, this will do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var theString = "9 days from now write about 'Go to market strategy' - 0.03 - 8100";
    var regEx = /Go to market strategy/;
    result = regEx.exec(theString);
    alert(result);

});
```

If you didn't want to use a regular expression, you need to update your question with more specifications on what you're actually trying to accomplish so we can provide more specific code. For right now, this solution utilizes a static regex.

Comment: They don't want to use regular expressions. Also, they need more of the string than just the specific text that's in the quotes - and this regex will only match this one reminder message, that message changes, so it's not going to match the next reminder message.

Comment: Yes, but the OP's question was unclear and not specific. Therefore, the most general 'catch all' answer if provided with the hope it will help guide the OP solve their problem. Oh, and the reasoning for using a regular expression is mentioned in the answer.